# Make parts of JTextPane non editable

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Alright, so I would like to do this: [Make parts of a JTextArea non editable (not the whole JTextArea!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030477/make-parts-of-a-jtextarea-non-editable-not-the-whole-jtextarea)

But on a JTextPane instead of a JTextArea, which does not seem to be possible using a DocumentFilter (?).

I tried the above solution on a JTextArea, and it works wonders. But I just can't find anything about how to do this on a JTextPane (if at all possible).

Well I did find this post: [Adding text to a JTextPane without having it editable by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974242/adding-text-to-a-jtextpane-without-having-it-editable-by-the-user)

But that's not quite what I'm looking for - I need my JTextPane to behave like a *command prompt*, like the JTextArea in the first link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a J*Pane of sorts - use JEditorPane. You can then use a DocumentBuilder and control its index so it will function much in the same way as your JTextArea example.

Comment: Does the JEditorPane support HTML formatting, buttons, icons etc? What's special with the EditorPane?

Comment: Absolutely! That is its main purpose. You set the 'document' of the JEditorPane in its constructor or dynamically by passing it to the constructor and the parameter "html/text". It supports everything short of complex CSS. Feel free to message me for more help ;)

Comment: Do you happen to have a good tutorial on your hands on how to use a DocumentBuilder? Or should I just visit google already ;)?

Comment: Well Ill consider my answer the accepted one I guess :) With Document Builder you just specify its type (for HTML: "html/text") and then append strings to the document builder such as "<b>Hello</b>". However, the first thing that goes into the document has to be the string "<html><body>" and the last thing "</body></html>". You should have no trouble using it right off but I do recommend that you look at the Java API for DocumentBuilder.

Comment: Yeah, if anything, it appears the JEditorPane works well with a DocumentFilter - and a good solution as to how to make parts of a text component uneditable using a DocumentFilter has already been brought up.
So, yeah, answer accepted :P